# Force iframe (on different domain) links to open in a new window

Tags: javascript, html

Contained within my web page is an iframe that's src is set to load a page from another domain.
This domain has links with `target="_top"`.

What I'm trying to achieve is, when someone clicks one of these links, I'd like it to open in a new window rather than load in the current window.

Is there any way to "catch" this and do what I require?

Thanks!

Comment: That's cross domain scripting and isn't allowed. It's kind of a hard no.

Comment: You don't have permission to do this - it's not your website, so JavaScript will prevent you from modifying the frame's content.

Comment: One could attempt an ugly hack running the page through php and alter all the links and then print it to the page, but that's really ugly and very prone to errors.

Comment: It's pretty clear the other site doesn't want you running their page in an iframe

Answer (score 1):

The domain has probably very good reasons to put `target="_top"` in their links. They don't want to be ran inside a(n) (i)frame. The correct answer to this is *"**No**, this can't be done."* Obvious security reasons prohibit us to do this.

You don't want somebody messing with your page by running it in an iframe. Phising and password retrieval becomes kind of easy when this is allowed. Browsers will not allow this these days.